# Docusign Connect / webhook error: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send

Tags: nginx, docusignapi

Not sure if this is a Docusign or ngix question.I'm working on integrating an application with Docusign and I keep seeing this somewhat vague error below in the Docusign Connect logs. In our nginx logs I see that a POST to our application's `/webhook` endpoint was attempted but doesn't go through. I've specified TLS 1.2 and have tried increasing our nginx timeout but that doesn't seem to fix it.

One theory I have is that our server's certificate isn't chained to a Microsoft trusted CA but I would expect a different error if that was the case.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Resolved: We had user authentication from the server blocking the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This most likely would require you to get the IT folks managing this server and networking involved. And yes, they may need to install a certificate, but other errors can be related to the firewall blocking certain requests, an anti-virus blocking requests and even DNS related error preventing the HTTP request from being sent and received by the server.
We highly recommend to use a public cloud for Connect and we have plenty of examples how this can work, while still having your code run on your own IT server.